# Is there a way to detect browser events (console) with vue/nuxt explicitly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, nuxt.js

Hello there i am currently working on an app where the dev-tools should be detected with vue/nuxt.
I found this package [detect devtools](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect), it works on `addEventListener()` with `window resize` but i wonder if there is way to continously detect this browser event with vue and or nuxt so the app can act with coming events from the console (dev-tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in "detect-devtools" documentation, we can get devtools value like this:

```
console.log('Is DevTools open:', window.devtools.isOpen);
```

The problem here is window object is not reactive.

If you don't mind a little delay, we can use an interval to update our reactive data:

```
  data: {
    devtools: null;
  },
  mounted() {
    this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
      this.devtools = window.devtools;
    }, 1000); // we use 1 second delay here
  },
  destroyed() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```